# Decorator design pattern java overriding methods question

Tags: java, oop, decorator

I need help understanding this example for a decorator:

```
    package design.decorator;
public class FillColorDecorator extends ShapeDecorator {
      protected Color color;
      public FillColorDecorator(Shape decoratedShape, Color color) {
            super(decoratedShape);
            this.color = color;
      }
      @Override
      public void draw() {
            decoratedShape.draw();
            System.out.println("Fill Color: " + color);
      }
      // no change in the functionality
      // we can add in the functionality if we like. there is no restriction
      // except we need to maintain the structure of the Shape APIs
      @Override
      public void resize() {
      decoratedShape.resize();
      }
      @Override
      public String description() {
      return decoratedShape.description() + " filled with " + color + " color.";
      }
      // no change in the functionality
      @Override
      public boolean isHide() {
      return decoratedShape.isHide();
      }
}
```

This example is taken from this website:
https://dzone.com/articles/decorator-design-pattern-in-java

I just don't understand why they bother to implement the methods with unchanged functionality. For exmple:

```
return decoratedShape.isHide();
```

Why is this necessary?
It seems to me that deleting this and not overriding the unchanged methods will do the job fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement them because in this case `ShapeDecorator` is only an abstract class implements `Shape`: it simply provide a uniform way to store the decorated `Shape`:

```java
package design.decorator;

public abstract class ShapeDecorator implements Shape {
      protected Shape decoratedShape;
      public ShapeDecorator(Shape decoratedShape) {
            super();
            this.decoratedShape = decoratedShape;
      }
}
```

You would not need it if in the `ShapeDecorator` class you were already doing that.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I wanted to add that requiring the approach that OP is asking about is a pretty bad programming practice.  When you're making a class that you plan for other people to extend (i.e. their ShapeDecorator class) you should think hard about how it will be used.  In a real Shape class, there would be dozens of methods, most of which the average Decorator would not want to modify.  They should have put do-nothing methods for every operation except, perhaps, for draw().